# Make a foreign key also a primary key in a Rails migration

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

**EDIT:**

I want a column to be a primary key and a foreign key from Rails' point of view. That is to say a foreign key using the `references` method. I'd like to do something like:

```
def change
  create_table :VipPerson, id: false do |t|
    t.primary_key :person_id
    t.references :person, :id, column: :person_id

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

I want to have a custom primary key that is also used by the Rails model to point to the Person-model (see below). This has actually nothing to do with foreign-keys that are employed by the sql-database (Rails didn't support the creation of real foreign-keys until Rails 4.2, as pointed out by Demi Magus).

-

I want to realize Multiple Table Interitance (MTI) in my Rails project and therefore realize inheritance like you usually do in a relational database:

```
table: Person
-------------
(PK) ID
Name
...

table: VipPerson (specalization of Person)
----------------
(PK) (FK) Person_ID
VIP-Status
...
```

So for this I need to write a migration that declares an attribute (here `Person_ID`) both as a (custom) primary key and a foreign key at the same time. I do not see how to do this with the methods of Rails' migration DSP.

I do not want to use Rails' polymorphic associations because I want to guarantee data integrity in the database. I know that I will need to customize the Rails model as well, but let's not get to that topic. The main problem is how to write a migration that makes a PK also an FK (or vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is manually setting the primary key and foreign key in the model rather than fiddling in the migration (note you must tell Rails not to create the default column id by passing "id: false" in the  options):

Migration:

```
def change
  create_table :VipPerson, id: false do |t|
    t.primary_key :person_id  # Normal integer PK, shouldn't auto-increment
    t.integer :vip_status
    ..... etc.
  end
end
```

In the model:

```
class VipPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "person_id"
  belongs_to :person, foreign_key: "person_id"
end
```

Just manually point to the same column in the model. On the database layer you can then additionally enhance the primary key with a real foreign-key contraint (see Demi Magus answer).

Answer (score 2):

The foreign key relation is only available with the latest version of rails, which is 4.2 as you can see in the [release notes](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/12/19/Rails-4-2-final/), and you can use it like this

Creating a simple foreign key

```
add_foreign_key :articles, :authors
```

generates:

```
ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD CONSTRAINT articles_author_id_fk FOREIGN KEY ("author_id") REFERENCES "authors" ("id")
```

You also should know that the add_foreign_key will only generate only a foreign key constraint, not a column like the activerecord add_column does

```
add_column :articles, :author_id, :integer
```

will generate:

```
ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD COLUMN author_id INT(11);
```

You can find more info [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key)

Also if you are not looking just for the edge of rails, then you could find useful this gem that allows you to do what you'r looking for which is [composite_primary_keys](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys), the only thing that you have to be cautious is that you will have to use the version compatible with your rails version.

I hope it helps :D

Comment: Actually this is indeed very helpful, thank you. I will also use that!
But maybe I should have been a bit mor specific. I want a column to be a foreign key and a primary key from Rails point of view. That is to say I want something like t.primary_key and t.references to map to the same column.
I added pseudocode to my original question.

Comment: Well if you didn't find it in the documentation then it's very probably that there's no way to do what you are looking for. Also the last version of Rails was released like a month ago so it's pretty new and difficult to find an expert about that. If you find my answer useful i will appreciate an upvote :D. Good luck ;D

Comment: Sorry if my formulation might have misguided you. My question is actually not limited to the latest version of Rails. The issue is in fact applicable since the beginning of ActiveRecord. A database construct like this is a common case and has been around way before Rails came in. I don't really believe that there's really no solution to this, since scenarios like this are rather common.
P.S. My rep is still too low to vote. Q___Q

Comment: don't worry XD. Mmm in that case, i've heard that there are gems for that, maybe this one could be helpful for you    https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys

Comment: Yep, i know this would help. But it always has to catch up with the Rails version.
Turns out there is a native way, but it requires some customization on the model-side rather than in the migrations. I'll post an answer.

Comment: well it's something, i've updated the answer anyway :p

Comment: Actually your answer is the perfect complement for my answer when you additionally want to guarantee referential integrity. :)